# Xcode Debugger : Show memory address for primitive types?

Tags: xcode, debugging

Per default der Xcode debugger only shows the memory address for objects and not for primitive typs like int or float. Is there a way to see the memory address of these types somehow?

Answer (score 2):

If you right-click on a row in the debugger, one option is "View As Memory" which gives you the data all around(or after) that variable. the "Address" field in the new  window will be the address of that variable.

I don't know how to make it display that in the main debugger window...

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that local variables may well be in registers and so may not even have an address as such.